# Como fazer 7 colunas com Bootstrap?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Tenho o seguinte menu abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como eu faria para que as colunas ficassem uma ao lado da outra (da primeira a sétima)?

Estou usando o Bootstrap 4. Tentei com o código abaixo, mas ficou essa bagunça da foto kkkk

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-9" style="border-right: 2px solid #FFF">
          <div class="row">

        <div class="col-md-2">
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-custom">
            <i class="fas fa-user-plus"></i>
          </a><br>
          Primeira coluna
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-custom">
            <i class="fas fa-user-plus"></i>
          </a><br>
        Segunda coluna
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-custom">
            <i class="fas fa-user-plus"></i>
          </a><br>
        Terceira Coluna
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-custom">
            <i class="fas fa-user-plus"></i>
          </a><br>
          Quarta Coluna
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-custom">
            <i class="fas fa-user-plus"></i>
          </a><br>
          Quinta Coluna
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-custom">
            <i class="fas fa-user-plus"></i>
          </a><br>
        Sexta Coluna
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-custom">
            <i class="fas fa-user-plus"></i>
          </a><br>
        Sétima Coluna
        </div>
  </div>
</div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <span>Compras Efetuadas:</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Você pode aumentar o tamanho do seu grid para um `col-md-12` e atribuir todas as colunas o tamanho de `col-md-2`, uma vai cair para baixo igual.

Comment: Olá Guilherme. Na verdade ela está 09, porque na coluna que tem 03 irá ser listado as compras efetuadas.

Answer (score 1):

Consegui resolver da seguinte forma:

**CSS**

```
@media (min-width: 768px){
  .seven-cols .col-md-1,
  .seven-cols .col-sm-1,
  .seven-cols .col-lg-1  {
    width: 100%;
    *width: 100%;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .seven-cols .col-md-1,
  .seven-cols .col-sm-1,
  .seven-cols .col-lg-1 {
    width: 14.285714285714285714285714285714%;
    *width: 14.285714285714285714285714285714%;
    max-width: 14.285714285714285714285714285714% !important;
flex:none !important;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .seven-cols .col-md-1,
  .seven-cols .col-sm-1,
  .seven-cols .col-lg-1 {
    width: 14.285714285714285714285714285714%;
    *width: 14.285714285714285714285714285714%;
    max-width: 14.285714285714285714285714285714% !important;
flex:none !important;
  }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="row seven-cols">
  <div class="col-md-1"></div>
  <div class="col-md-1"></div>
  <div class="col-md-1"></div>
  <div class="col-md-1"></div>
  <div class="col-md-1"></div>
  <div class="col-md-1"></div>
  <div class="col-md-1"></div>
</div>
```

[Fonte do código](https://gist.github.com/amilabandara/22861dab8604ce55c33c7c9aa9919d20)

Answer (score 1):

@Fox.11. Analisando o seu código, o framework do Bootstrap permite que você crie no máximo 12 colunas em uma página, ou até mesmo dentro de uma linha (*row*). Elas não estão alinhadas, pois somando todos os *col-md-**x*** que você colocou, você quer criar 16 colunas para posicionar as 7 colunas (blocos) neste container.

---

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
Você pode corrigir a numeração das colunas ou de uma forma mais simples, definir um id para todas estas divs que contem a classe de col-md-... e no CSS fazer a seguinte aplicação:

---

Exemplo:

```css
#id_bloco{
  float: left;
  width: 14.2%; /*Seria a largura total 100% dividida por 7 colunas*/
}
```

```html
<div id="id_bloco">BLOCO 1</div>
<div id="id_bloco">BLOCO 2</div>
<div id="id_bloco">BLOCO 3</div>
<div id="id_bloco">BLOCO 4</div>
<div id="id_bloco">BLOCO 5</div>
<div id="id_bloco">BLOCO 6</div>
<div id="id_bloco">BLOCO 7</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Seguinte, o grid do Bootstrap é baseado em flex, então automaticamente ele já vai dividir as `divs` em tamanhos iguais, mas para isso vc não pode definis explicitamente o valor dessas `divs`, então a primeira coisa a fazer é remover o `col-md-2` das `divs` dentro da `row`.

Depois disso vc vai usar essas classes `Flex` originais do Bootstrap. Essas classes vc vai botar na `row` que é o pai das 7 `divs`. E como falei nas 7 `divs` vc  tira a classe `col-md-2`

**`justify-content-between`**: Vai espaçar as 7 `divs` igualmente dentro do container `row`
**`flex-lg-row`**: Até telas `lg` ou 992px as `div` ficam uma ao lado da outra
**`flex-column`**: Em telas menores que `lg` vai ficar uma `div` por linha
**`flex-nowrap`**: Não deixa a `div` cair pra linha de baixo mesmo tendo muito conteúdo
<sub>(a div nuna vai cair pra linha de baixo, o que vamos fazer a mudar a orientação de horizonta, para vertical "column" quando a tela for menor que `lg`)</sub>

```
<div class="row justify-content-between flex-column flex-lg-row flex-nowrap"> 7 divs </div>
```

Documentação oficial do Flex Bootstrap: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/utilities/flex/

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Segue o código referente ao exemplo da imagem acima:
 *(repare que não tem CSS além do original do Bootstrap)***

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-9" style="border-right: 2px solid #FFF">
            <div class="row justify-content-between flex-column flex-lg-row flex-nowrap">
  
          <div class=" ">
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-custom">
              <i class="fas fa-user-plus"></i>
            </a><br>
            Primeira coluna
          </div>
          <div class=" ">
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-custom">
              <i class="fas fa-user-plus"></i>
            </a><br>
          Segunda coluna
          </div>
          <div class=" ">
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-custom">
              <i class="fas fa-user-plus"></i>
            </a><br>
          Terceira Coluna
          </div>
          <div class=" ">
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-custom">
              <i class="fas fa-user-plus"></i>
            </a><br>
            Quarta Coluna
          </div>
          <div class=" ">
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-custom">
              <i class="fas fa-user-plus"></i>
            </a><br>
            Quinta Coluna
          </div>
          <div class=" ">
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-custom">
              <i class="fas fa-user-plus"></i>
            </a><br>
          Sexta Coluna
          </div>
          <div class=" ">
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-custom">
              <i class="fas fa-user-plus"></i>
            </a><br>
          Sétima Coluna
          </div>
    </div>
  </div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <span>Compras Efetuadas:</span>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Existe dois conceitos novos dentro do Bootstrap 4. Você pode optar pelo conceito de Flex Box ou pelo tradicional conceito de blocos.

Minha recomendação para o bloco que você tá seguindo, é que você tente pensar no tamanho das colunas como algo que deve atender o grid de 12 colunas para seguirem em linha.

```css
.bloco {
display:flex;
align-items:center;
justify-content:center;
height:50px;
width:100%;
background-color:#ccc;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-xl-9 col-lg-9 col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-9">
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-1">
     <div class="bloco">1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-1">
     <div class="bloco">1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-1">
     <div class="bloco">1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-1">
     <div class="bloco">1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-1">
     <div class="bloco">1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-1">
     <div class="bloco">1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-1">
     <div class="bloco">1</div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xl-3 col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3">
   <!-- Espaço vazio -->
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Mas eu gosto do conceito de Flex Box onde você pode brincar com os espaçamentos proporcionais pelo justify-content ou pelo align-items.